# Speed up linq query without where clauses

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq

Quick LINQ performance question.

I have a database with many many records and it's used for a webshop.

All query logic and paging is done with LINQ, and it performs quite well. 
This is, because the usual search for products contains one or more where clause, and that shortens my result set to a couple of hundred results at max. 
But.. there is an option to list all products (when no search criteria is provided), and that query is slow.. real slow. Even though i'm just asking for a single page with .Skip(20).Take(10), it's still slow because the total result is something like 140000 products. Is there a way to limit this (or all) query, so that the speed of the whole thing is kept okay? 
I don't want to force my customers to provide one or more criteria.. but on the other hand i have no problem with telling them that they can never find more than 2000 products.

Thanks for helping! 
Tys

Comment: Can you post your query code? Can you post the generated SQL?

Comment: If you are using ".Skip(20).Take(10)", the the result should be 10 rows, not 140000; if you are getting 140000 you have done something horribly wrong (probably made it non-composable too early, via ToList, IEnuemrable, etc). We can't guess *what* - only the code will tell you. However, there are tools that will tell you.

Comment: Are you sure you're `Skip`- and `Take`-ing on the `IQueryable<T>` and not an `IEnumerable<T>` (aka have you already buffered the entire result in memory)?

Comment: It's not that i'm really getting 140000 results, i'm getting 10. It's just that the total set that matches my 'no criteria search' is 140000, and that's what made me think that that could possibly be a problem..

Comment: I am doing a .Count on a copy of my query, to get that total nr of records, could that be a problem? I need that number to know how many paging buttons we should draw..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to have Linq use stored procedure from the database.

In that case, it will be faster because it is the database engine who will do the work and return it to Linq; the database engine is made for that, and it is closer to data than Linq.

I suggest you give it a try and give us feedback

Comment: Playing around with LINQPad helped me a bit. And for the rest we moved some code over to the SQL server. LINQ is very nice to do a lot of things, but this complex query we are running performs way better directly on SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you limit the number of records on the sql side as described in this post
http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/06/skip-and-take-n-number-of-records-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for any "premature" enumerations when you pass down queries/results in your code!

There are also several LINQ visualizers available, which can help to see what the LINQ expressions actually translate to. Or you can play around with expressions in LINQPad before integrating in your code…

Comment: Playing around with LINQPad helped me a bit. And for the rest we moved some code over to the SQL server. LINQ is very nice to do a lot of things, but this complex query we are running performs way better directly on SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what indexes has the table and what PK is. It could be the table has no index at all so records compared by field values. Also you can catch the query in the SqlProfiler, run it separately and analyse its query plan.